# Cannot find the object "TABLE" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know there are N no of solutions with same title and after 3 days and useless running through them all I have to post it here.

I've an UserDetailDAC.cs like this:-

```
public UserDetails ValidateUserAdmin(string Usrname, string pwd)
    {
        using (var db = new HostelManagementContext())
        {
            //IEnumerable<UserDetails> linq;
            //string query = "SELECT* FROM UserDetails WHERE UserName ='" + Usrname + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND UserPwd = '" + pwd + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS";
            //linq = db.Database.SqlQuery<UserDetails>(query);
            //return linq.FirstOrDefault();
            return db.Set<UserDetails>().Where(x => x.UserName == Usrname && x.UserPwd == pwd).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

and my HostelManagementContext.cs is like this :-

```
 public HostelManagementContext() : base("ConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<HostelManagementContext, HostelModel.Migrations.Configuration>("ConnectionString"));
        //Database.SetInitializer<HostelManagementContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<HostelManagementContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<CandidateHostelBookingMapping> CandidateHostelBookingMappings { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }
```

Now when I try to run this it gives me below error:-

```
Cannot find the object "CandidateHostelBookingMappings" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

This is Entity Framework Code first approach. Please feel free to ask any further details

Answer (score 0):

//Are you use Migration for creating database and table using package manager console ?

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName HostelManagementContext 
add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName -----
update-database -ProjectName
```

Comment: Yes we are using Migrations. Can you pls explain in detail as why is this happening?